How to preserve new lines from command output printed out using Write-Host in PowerShell?
I have recently (2-3 days ago) started to use Powershell. I have a C++ application that uses argparse to process some command line arguments. If something is not as expected, my code exits with the help string provided by -/--help flag of any application that uses this library.
I use (output from $PSVersionTable):
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.2364
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.2364
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

I have a CMake configuration file
Write-Host "${APP_NAME} (${BUILD_TYPE})"

$model = ""
$data_in = ""

Write-Host "Checking input arguments"
if ($args.count -ne 5)
{
    Write-Host "Found {0} arguments but expecting 5" -f $args.count
    Write-Host $(./pytorch_load_model.exe --help) -foregroundcolor Cyan
    exit
}

for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $args.count; $i++ ) {
    if (($args[ $i ] -eq "-m") -or ($args[ $i ] -eq "--model")){ $model=$args[ $i+1 ]}
    if (($args[ $i ] -eq "-i") -or ($args[ $i ] -eq "--input")){ $data_in=$args[ $i+1 ]}
}

$fail = $false
if ($model -eq "")
{
    Write-Host "No path for model provided"
}
if ($data_in -eq "")
{
    Write-Host "No path for input provided"
}
if ($fail -eq $true)
{
    Write-Host (./model.exe --help)
    exit
}

# TODO Add check if $opencv and $libtorch valid dir paths
$opencv = "${OPENCV_BIN}"
$libtorch = "${LIBTORCH_BIN}"
#$model = "${PTH_MODEL_PATH}"
#$input = "${INPUT_IMG_PATH}"
Write-Host "Executing model"
$env:Path="$($env:Path);$($opencv);$($libtorch)"; ./pytorch_load_model.exe -m "$($model)" -i "$($data_in)"

which is processed by using configure_file() to output a script (*.ps1 file) that is added to the binary directory of my project (EXE, dlls and other runtime-relevant data). It sets up PATH so that the application runs as expected and also passes through the same command line argument as my application expects.
I have noticed that Write-Host "eats up" all of the new lines that come out as a multiline string from my application.
Instead of
PyTorch Load Model (release)
Checking input arguments
Usage: model [--help] [--version] [--model-path VAR] [--png-path VAR]

Optional arguments:
  -h, --help        shows help message and exits
  -v, --version     prints version information and exits
  -m, --model-path  Path to PTH TorchScript model
  -i, --png-path    Path to PNG image to be processed by the model

I receive
Usage: model [--help] [--version] [--model-path VAR] [--png-path VAR]  Optional arguments:   -h, --help        shows help message and exits    -v, --version     prints version information and exits    -m, --model-path  Path to PTH TorchScript model    -i, --png-path    Path to PNG image to be processed by the model

How do I preserve the new lines?

are you using powershell 5.1 or 7.x?
Most likely it's encoding shenanigans from a cmd.exe application to Powershell

@sirtao I added the info in the OP.

Pipe the output to write-host: (./model.exe --help) | write-host

As @nimizen suggests, the best option seems to be piping: (./model.exe --help) | write-host
As alternative workaround you can use ((./model.exe --help) -join "`r`n")


sirtao's helpful answer shows effective solutions.

As for what you tried:

When PowerShell calls an external program, it streams its stdout output line by line to the PowerShell pipeline.

When enclosing such a call in (...) - such as in order to pass the output as a command argument, as in this case - the lines are of necessity collected in an array (of type [object[]]), assuming there are two or more lines.

Write-Host, when given an array as an argument, prints the (stringified) elements of the array on a single line, separated with a single space each - this is what you saw:

A simple example:
# -> 'foo bar'
Write-Host @('foo', 'bar')


In order to achieve multiline output (both techniques are shown in sirtao's answer):

Either: Provide the output produced by your external-program call (e.g., ./model.exe --help)  via the pipeline, which causes Write-Host to print each pipeline input object on its own line.

Or: Explicitly join the lines output by the external programs with newlines to form a single, multiline string, which Write-Host prints as is.

As an alternative to the -join solution in sirtao's answer, you can use the Out-String cmdlet; e.g.:
 Write-Host -NoNewLine (./model.exe --help | Out-String)


Note the use of -NoNewLine, which compensates for the unfortunate fact that Out-String adds a trailing newline to the multiline output string it produces; this problematic behavior is discussed in GitHub issue #14444.










Optional reading: Appropriate uses for Write-Host, producing colored stderr output:

Write-Host is typically the wrong tool to use, unless the intent is to write to the display only, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it by itself; e.g., $value instead of Write-Host $value (or use Write-Output $value, though that is rarely needed). See also: the bottom section of this answer.

That said, in PowerShell v5.1 and above you can capture and redirect Write-Host output, namely via the information output stream, whose number is 6; e.g., to redirect that stream to the success output stream, use redirection 6>&1


Write-Host is the appropriate tool to use for building an interactive user experience, notably if you're trying to create colored output with the -ForegroundColor and -BackgroundColor parameters, such as in your case.

That said, you now also have the option to embed ANSI/VT escape sequences in strings, which allows them to be sent to the success output stream and therefore to be captured or redirected directly; e.g., in PowerShell (Core) 7, using the $PSStyle preference variable to facilitate embedding the escape sequences:
# Produces the same *display* output as:
#   Write-Host -Foreground Cyan 'This prints in cyan.'
# Unlike the latter, it outputs to the success output stream.
"$($PSStyle.Foreground.Cyan)This prints in cyan.$($PSSTyle.Reset)"

# Windows PowerShell equivalent, where $PSStyle isn't available.
# See the "ANSI/VT escape sequences" link above for details.
"$([char] 27 + '[36m')This prints in cyan.$([char] 27 + '[m')"


If you want to apply coloring conditionally, namely only when the PowerShell process' stdout (success stream) is connected to a terminal, use [Console]::IsOutputRedirected (use [Console]::IsErrorRedirected for stderr).


However, in your case, given that you're indicating an error condition (an unexpected number of arguments), it would be more appropriate to print the message to the stderr stream of the PowerShell process.

PowerShell-internally, using its loosely analogous stream, the error output stream, via Write-Error is not an option in Windows PowerShell, because any message passed to it will invariably print in red and, by default, noisily as a multiline string; in PowerShell (Core) 7, you can override the red coloring via embedded ANSI/VT escape sequences, but a Write-Error: prefix will still invariably print, in red.

However, if using PowerShell's error stream session-internally isn't important, you can use [Console]::Error.WriteLine() to print directly to the stderr stream of the PowerShell process (thereby forgoing the ability to capture the output intra-session):
# PowerShell 7:
# Print directly to stderr, with ANSI/VT-sequence coloring:
[Console]::Error.WriteLine(
  "$($PSStyle.Foreground.Cyan)This prints in cyan.$($PSSTyle.Reset)"
)


To demonstrate the conditional coloring technique, where coloring is only used when stderr is connected to a terminal:
 # PowerShell 7:
 # Print directly to stderr, with ANSI/VT-sequence coloring 
 # applied only when connected to a terminal.
 [Console]::Error.WriteLine(
   "$([Console]::IsErrorRedirected ? '' : $PSStyle.Foreground.Cyan)This prints in cyan when connected to a terminal.$([Console]::IsErrorRedirected ? '' : $PSSTyle.Reset)"
 )










Great explanation, very useful

Instead of Write-Host you could use "Write-Output" which simply passes the values to the output stream. Whereas Write-Host turns the data into screen output only and unless you are changing font colors is never really needed.

Also a good option though I would like to use the coloring. :D
